# Grafana-loki not showing labels of all the deployments

Tags: grafana-loki

I somehow broke my Grafana+loki+promtail setup and was not able to fix it.
In grafana, I am seeing only two values in app labels. It supposes to show 21 values(it was working fine some days back)

[image]

I also checked the promtail as well I see all the targets is having this labels `app="xxxxxxxx"`
This mean promtail is adding the label on the logs but why its not showing in Grafana?